# Buefy datepicker with Laravel: Expected Date, got String

Tags: laravel, vue.js, buefy

I have a form that is populated by data received from an API request to my backend.

I am using v-model to bind the data to the fields (for example):

```
<input type="text" v-model="fields.name">
```

Everything works just fine. But when it comes to **Buefy datepicker** I get the following warning:

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Date, got String.

This is correct since this is the value I get back from Laravel is "2019-02-01 00:00:00". I am trying to parse this String to a Date using the Buefy property **date-parser** but with no luck:

```
<b-datepicker
     :date-parser="(date) => new Date(Date.parse(date))"
     v-model="fields.budget_date"
     :first-day-of-week="1"
     placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
     name="order_date"
     editable>
</b-datepicker>
```

## Update:

This is the data object:

```
data() {
  return {
    csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
    fields: {},
    errors: {},
    success: false,
    loaded: true,
    loading: false,
}
```

Then I use **Axios.get** to fetch the data from the server and assign them to the fields object like so:

```
this.fields = response.data;
```

This is how is see the fields.budget_date in Vue DevTools:

[image]

Any idea how to overcome this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: i think the problem is with `v-model="fields.order_date"`

Comment: Is it because the fields object is not reactive like normal data props?

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean, please share your data object  `data(){...}`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim please see updated. Just changed the order_date to budget_date to match the image.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem in a wrapper component around Buefy's `b-datepicker` component.

The solution can be derived from christostsang's answer which is to pass in the initial value wrapped in `new Date()`.

My wrapper component prop type looks like this:

```
initialValue: {
    type: Date,
    required: false,
    default: () => undefined,
},
```

and it is used like this:

```
<my-datepicker
    :initial-value="new Date(something.renews_on)"
></my-datepicker>
```

I'm using mostly the default props from `b-datepicker`, but my wrapper component is using this:

```
<b-datepicker
    v-model="value"
    :initial-value="initialValue"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    :name="name"
    :date-formatter="dateFormatter"
    :date-parser="dateParser"
    :date-creator="dateCreator"
    ... etc
```

...

```
dateFormatter: {
    type: Function,
    required: false,
    default: date => date.toLocaleDateString(),
},
dateParser: {
    type: Function,
    required: false,
    default: date => new Date(Date.parse(date)),
},
dateCreator: {
    type: Function,
    required: false,
    default: () => new Date(),
},
```

You can investigate the default props here: https://buefy.org/documentation/datepicker

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out.

The warning is pretty clear: **Don't use a string here, use a Date object.**

So after getting the response from the server, I parsed the string value into Date object and then bind it to v-model:

```
this.fields.budget_date = new Date(this.fields.budget_date)
```

So now I get this into Vue DevTools:

[image]

As you can see the budget_date is of the correct Date format, unlike created_at which is a string.

> Parser function (**:date-parser**) gives you the correct Date object during user date selection.

What I wanted was to set the v-model value based on the data stored in my database. And for the b-datepicker to work that needs to be Date object, not String.